# mysql command doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that has something like this

```
id    nam        start_t    end_t
51    something  2014-10-01 0000-00-00
```

I want to change the end_t to "2014-9-31" so i used this command

```
"UPDATE `sometable` SET `end_t`="2014-9-31" WHERE id=51 limit 1"
```

However, the above code just sets the end_t to 0000-00-00...

These queries work fine though

```
"UPDATE `sometable` SET `end_t`="2014-10-31" WHERE id=51 limit 1"
"UPDATE `sometable` SET `end_t`="2014-8-31" WHERE id=51 limit 1"
```

EDIT: Wow... I feel stupid ~.~ thanks soo much for the feedback

Comment: 30 days has September, April, June, and November.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using **single quotes** for values?

Comment: Double quotes are also fine @itsols

Comment: double quotes may not work because when you use it it end the sring after end_t so date is out of string . u can use single quote when query start with double quote

Comment: Thats how they have presented their query. That could even be a formatting thing that they put double quotes around their queries to show us those. Nothing prevents mysql from understanding that something inside double quotes is as good a value as it is inside single quotes. you can also see the end of their question where they mention the values that work fine with double quotes. Quotation marks are really irrelevant to this question. Its the invalid date that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come on, September doesnt have 31 days

```
="2014-9-31"    // 30 max :)
```

Since that is a date field, it knows which date is valid and which is not. That's why when you send an invalid date to it it sets the value to default and not to that invalid date.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought i read somewhere that mysql doesn't check the max number of days and you can just put 31 to use as max thanks

Comment: If that was a text field mysql wouldnt care, but when it is a date field mysql has to care. Just like you cant put abc in a numeric field.

Answer (score 0):

Because september does not have 31 days

change it like this

```
"UPDATE sometable SET end_t="2014-9-30" WHERE id=51 limit 1"
```